# Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in top flight domestic league (European clubs)

Tags: football, trivia, records

When Messi passed 300 goals for Barcelona, I asked this question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere. Who has scored more goals than Messi for a single club?

Edit:
I was specifically asking for the goals in the domestic league that's why I've created separate questions for the goals in all the competitions.

Related questions:

- [Players with 400 or more goals for a single team in all competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13145/players-with-400-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-all-competitions-european-c)
- [Players with 300 or more goals in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/players-with-300-or-more-goals-in-top-flight-domestic-league-european-clubs)
- [Players with 400 or more goals in all club competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/players-with-400-or-more-goals-in-all-club-competitions-european-clubs)

Comment: [Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller) scored for Bayern Munich 398 goals in Bundesliga, and 566 goals in all competitions. I do not know whether it is record, but it is certainly impressive.

Comment: And, of course, there is [Pelé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pel%C3%A9#Career_statistics).The numbers for him differ, based on who is counting and which matches are counted. But there are certainly at least 600 goals in official matches for Santos.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about European clubs. I also have checked the most famous footballers and I can see their goals. I just wondered if there is a list that contains all of them?

Comment: I am not sure to which extent [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_top_association_football_goal_scorers) is reliable. But if that list is correct, it contains all players with more than 560 goals throughout their career (including both club and national matches). So they are the only possible candidates for scoring more than  Müller's 566. But since the Wikipedia article comes with the banner saying "This article's factual accuracy is disputed," it would be nice to find a more reliable source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have started a CW answer, where various users can add players they find (or occasionally update numbers for active players). I guess in this way we can find at least an approximation of a complete list.

We could get very different numbers depending on which competitions we count (for example, all competitions including European cups, all domestic competitions including domestic cups and lower level leagues). To make this list correspond to the OP, let us only count **top-level domestic leagues**. (I.e., we don't count cups, only league matches in the top-level league.)

### Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in a top-flight domestic league (European clubs)

1. [Lionel Messi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi#Career_statistics) (Barcelona/La Liga) **474**<sup>1</sup>
2. [Uwe Seeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uwe_Seeler) (Hamburger SV/Oberliga & Bundesliga) **404**<sup>2</sup>
3. [Jimmy McGrory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_McGrory#Career_statistics) (Celtic Glasgow/Scottish League) **395**<sup>3</sup>
4. [Josef Bican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Bican) (Slavia Prague/Czechoslovak First League) **395**<sup>4</sup>
5. [Ferenc Szusza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Szusza) (Újpest/Hungarian League) **393**
6. [Gyula Zsengellér](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyula_Zsengell%C3%A9r) (Újpest/Hungarian League) **368**
7. [Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller) (Bayern Munich/Bundesliga) **365**
8. [Ferenc Puskás](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s#Career_statistics) (Budapest Honvéd/National Championship I) **352**
9. [Albert De Cleyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_De_Cleyn) (KV Mechelen/Belgian First Division) **350**<sup>6</sup>
10. [Joseph Mermans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Mermans) (Anderlecht/Belgian First Division) **339**
11. [Fernando Peyroteo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Peyroteo) (Sporting/Primeira Liga) **329**<sup>6</sup>
12. [Eusébio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eus%C3%A9bio#Career_statistics) (Benfica/Primeira Divisão) **317**
13. [Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo#Career_statistics) (Real Madrid/La Liga) **311**
14. [Dixie Dean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixie_Dean) (Everton/First Division) **310**<sup>7</sup>
15. [Willy van der Kuijlen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_van_der_Kuijlen) (PSV Eindhoven/Eredivisie) **308**

Players marked in bold still play in the given club and competition.

<sup>1</sup>As of 7 August 2021
<sup>2</sup>404 goals for Hamburger SV, if we count both Oberliga and Bundesliga; 137 if we only count Bundesliga. (Oberliga was the highest level competition in the North of Germany before the [foundation of Bundesliga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_of_the_Bundesliga).)
<sup>3</sup>395 according to stats at Wikipedia, 397 according to RSSSF.
<sup>4</sup>The number 395 is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Bican). [RSSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/tablest/tsjsltops-allt.html) lists separately 218 goals in Czechoslovak competitions and 232 goals in the era of Protectorate of Bohemia and Moravia. His stats at RSSSF are not broken down by the team, only total number of goals is given.
<sup>5</sup>377 according to [Albert De Cleyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_De_Cleyn) Wikipedia page, 350 according to [RSSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/tablesb/belgtops-allt.html) and [Belgian Pro League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_Pro_League#Top_scorers) Wikipedia page.
<sup>6</sup>330 according to RSSSF.
<sup>7</sup>308 according to RSSSF.

### Sources

- Wikipedia articles about individual players
- [List of League All-Time Topscorers](http://www.rsssf.com/miscellaneous/alltime-tops.html) at RSSSF
- [Top 10 Goalscorers in Bundesliga History](http://www.therichest.com/sports/soccer-sports/top-10-goalscorers-in-bundesliga-history/)
- Das große Buch der Fußball-Rekorde by Omar Gisler, [page 40](https://books.google.sk/books?id=OxswOvHm3FEC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40)
- Wikipedia article on [Belgian Pro League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_Pro_League#Top_scorers) and and [RSSSF Archive](http://www.rsssf.com/tablesb/belgtops-allt.html)
- [Top Division English League Goal Scorers 1888-2015](http://www.free-elements.com/England/ts0.html)
- [England - All-Time Topscorers](http://www.rsssf.com/tablese/engtops-allt.html) at RSSSF
- [Portugal - All-Time Topscorers](http://www.rsssf.com/tablesp/porttops-allt.html) at RSSSF
- [Scotland - All-Time Topscorers](http://www.rsssf.com/tabless/scottops-allt.html) at RSSSF
- Hungarian league top scorers at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemzeti_Bajnoks%C3%A1g_I#Records) nad [RSSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/tablesh/hongtops-allt.html)
- [Spanish football top scorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_football_top_scorers#All-time_top_scorers_in_La_Liga) at Wikipedia
- [The top scorers in European league history](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=2185739.html) at uefa.com
- [Meet Europe's most prolific scorer of all time](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/association=cze/news/newsid=2190403.html) at uefa.com
- [Lionel Messi breaks into top 10 all-time scorers list for Europe's top leagues...](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2975551/Lionel-Messi-breaks-10-time-scorers-list-Europe-s-leagues.html) - Daily Mail
- [Greatest goalscorers of individual clubs](http://footyroom.com/forum/football-talk/greatest-goalscorers-of-individual-clubs-57617) at Footyroom forum.
- [World Best As per IFFHS](http://www.xtratime.org/forum/showthread.php?t=60730) at Xtratune forum.
- [The 'Messis' from the world's best leagues](http://www.marca.com/en/2014/11/24/en/football/barcelona/1416867468.html) at marca.com
- [The top scorers in European league history](https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2185739.html#/) - UEFA ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180115201817/https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2185739.html))

Answer (score 5):

This is a list of retired players I have found:

- Ferenc Puskás scored 374 goals in 358 matches for Budapest Honvéd, where he played from 1943 to 1956
- Ian Rush scored 346 goals in 660 appearances for Liverpool in two spells from 1980 to 1987 and then from 1988 to 1996
- Alfredo Stéfano di Stéfano Laulhé scored 307 goals in 396 appearances for Real Madrid from 1953 to 1964
- Eusébio scored 473 goals in 440 appearances during his 15 year spell at Benfica
- Steve Bull scored 306 goals in 561 appearances for Wolverhampton Wanderers
- Pelé scored 643 goals in 656 appearances for Santos, a team he played with for eighteen years
- Raúl González Blanco scored 323 goals in 741 appearances for Real Madrid between 1994 and 2010
- Gerd Müller scored 566 goals in 607 matches for Bayern Munich between 1964 and 1979
- Uwe Seeler scored 444 goals in 519 games for Hamburger SV between 1954 and 1972

Disclaimer: This list is by no means exhaustive. Just a list of some players who scored a hell of a lot of goals for their respective clubs.