# Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in all competitions (European clubs)

Tags: football, trivia, records

Having already started a discussion for the players that has 300 or more goals in top flight domestic league for an European club let's distinguish a question for players with more than 400 goals in all competitions for a single club in Europe. Excluding friendly matches.

Related questions:

- [Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/players-with-300-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-top-flight-domestic-league)
- [Players with 300 or more goals in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/players-with-300-or-more-goals-in-top-flight-domestic-league-european-clubs)
- [Players with 400 or more goals in all club competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/players-with-400-or-more-goals-in-all-club-competitions-european-clubs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two rankings by the [FCBarcelona.com](https://www.fcbarcelona.com/football/first-team/news/2016-2017/leo-messi-draws-level-with-eusebio-for-number-of-goals-with-the-same-club) official page and Spanish paper [Sport](https://scontent.fsof3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15094361_728606243964390_8453748507702950649_n.jpg?oh=d3b68ec97ae2519a13d8d802e76f4e6f&oe=58B32071), which are used as the most reliable ones (for the retired players).
Pele's goals are not scored in Europe, anyway, they are pointed as an ultimate achievement.

As per 5 June 2023:

| # | Player | Team | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Lionel Messi](https://messi.starplayerstats.com/en/goals/5/0/all/0/0/0/t/all/all/0/1/1) | [Barcelona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FC_Barcelona_records_and_statistics#Top_goalscorers) | 672 |
| - | *[Pelé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pel%C3%A9#Club_2)* | *Santos* | *643* |
| 2 | [Josef Bican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Bican) | Slavia Prague | 534 |
| 3 | [Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller#Club_career_statistics) | [Bayern München](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FC_Bayern_Munich_records_and_statistics#Goalscorers) | 525(564<sup>1</sup>) |
| 4 | [Jimmy McGrory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_McGrory) | [Celtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Celtic_F.C._records_and_statistics#Top_goalscorers) | 522 |
| 5 | [Uwe Seeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uwe_Seeler) | Hamburger | 507 |
| 6 | [Eusebio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eus%C3%A9bio#Career_statistics) | [Benfica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S.L._Benfica_records_and_statistics#Top_goalscorers) | 473 |
| 7 | [Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo#Career_statistics) | [Real Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Real_Madrid_CF_records_and_statistics#Goalscorers) | 450 |
| 8 | [José Águas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_%C3%81guas#Statistics) | Benfica | 379 |
| 9 | [Nené](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nen%C3%A9_(footballer,_born_1949)) | Benfica | 359 |
| 10 | [Karim Benzema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karim_Benzema#Career_statistics) | Real Madrid | 354 |
| 11 | [Ian Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Rush#Career_statistics) | [Liverpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Liverpool_F.C._records_and_statistics#Top_goalscorers) | 346 |
| 12 | [Robert Lewandowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lewandowski#Career_statistics) | Bayern Munich | 344 |
| 13 | [Telmo Zarra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telmo_Zarra) | [Athletic Bilbao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Athletic_Bilbao_records_and_statistics#Top_goalscorers) | 336 |
| 14 | [Raúl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%C3%BAl_(footballer)#Career_statistics) | Real Madrid | 323 |
| 15 | [Alfredo Di Stéfano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_Di_St%C3%A9fano#Club) | Real Madrid | 307 |

<sup>1</sup> Gerd Müller has scored 39 more goals in 1964-65 season for Bayern in Regionalliga Süd, which existed as the second tier of the German football league system from 1963 to 1974.