# Players with 300 or more goals in top flight domestic league (European clubs)

Tags: football, trivia, records

Who are the players that has more than 300 goals in top flight domestic league, combined for all the teams that they have played.

Related questions:

- [Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/players-with-300-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-top-flight-domestic-league)
- [Players with 400 or more goals for a single team in all competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13145/players-with-400-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-all-competitions-european-c)
- [Players with 400 or more goals in all club competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/players-with-400-or-more-goals-in-all-club-competitions-european-clubs)

Comment: Some of such players could be found on [page 22](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VXixt.png) of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=OxswOvHm3FEC&pg=PA22).

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking about goals scored *in the same competition* or in *all domestic leagues* where the player played? For example, for [Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo#Career_statistics) should we count together his goals in Primeira Liga, Permier League and La Liga, which yields 3+84+252=339? Or only his goal from La Liga, where he scored 252 and thus he would not qualify for this question?

Comment: All domestic league, in the case with Ronaldo La Liga + Premier League.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this could be a reliable list, but maybe not exact, of players with more goals in the top flight domestic leagues in the world. I only consider goals in national leagues but I don´t consider goals in regional or state leagues, for example, the state championships in Brazil or the Oberliga in Germany before Bundesliga. That's why names like Pele, Romario, or Uwe Seeler with a lot of goals in regional championships are not on this list.

The list is updated to 28 May 2023.

1. Josef Bican 518 (Bohemia and Moravia 241, Czechoslovakia 206, Austria 71)
2. Ferenc Puskás 514 (Hungary 358, Spain 156)
3. **Cristiano Ronaldo 498 (Spain 311, England 103, Italy 81, Portugal 3)**
4. **Lionel Messi 496 (Spain 474, France 22)**
5. Imre Schlosser 417 (Hungary 411, Austria 6)
6. Gyula Zsengellér 416 (Hungary 387, Colombia 23, Italy 6)
7. Jimmy McGrory 408 (Scotland)
8. Gerd Müller 405 (Germany 365, USA 40)
9. Hugo Sánchez 400 (Spain 234, Mexico 123, USA 37, Austria 6)
10. **Zlatan Ibrahimović 393 (340 in Europe) (Sweden 4, Netherlands 35, Italy 155, Spain 16, France 113, England 17, USA 53)**
11. Ferenc Szusza 393 (Hungary)
12. Carlos Bianchi 385 (Argentina 206, France 179)
13. Alfredo Di Stefano 376 (Spain 227, Colombia 90, Argentina 59)
14. Gunnar Nordahl 374 (Italy 225, Sweden 149)
15. Jimmy Greaves 366 (England 357, Italy 9)
16. Hughie Ferguson 363 (Scotland 286, England 77)
17. József Takács 360 (Hungary)
18. Hans Krankl 354 (Austria 320, Spain 34)
19. **Luis Suárez 353 (329 in Europe) (Uruguay 14, Netherlands 91, England 69, Spain 179)**
20. Delio Onnis 352 (France 299, Argentina 53)
21. György Sárosi 351 (Hungary)
22. Osvaldo Castro 351 (Mexico 214, Chile 137)
23. Albert De Cleyn 350 (Belgium)
24. Victor Hugo Antelo 350 (Bolivia)

Comment: may be worth making this a wiki answer so @Lipata can update easily?

Answer (score -2):

There are several players who have scored over 300 goals in top flight league.
In the current scenario they they are:
1. Cristiano Ronaldo (442 goals)
2. Lionel Messi (440 goals)
3. Zlatan Ibrahimovic (372 goals)

There are other players like Gerd Muller, Jimmy Graves, Pele and Bican.

It's very unfair of people not counting the Brazilian leagues as the top flight domestic league because in 1960s Brazilian team regularly defeated European teams with ease.

Thus Bican, Pele and then Messi and Ronaldo comes up, out of all the players Pele and Josep Bican has the highest goal ration followed by Gerd Muller, Messi and Ronaldo.

Comment: You can count the Brazilian league in. We're already counting Mexico, Argentina, etc. Feel free to edit additional players into the post above. In the Serie A Pelé only had 100 goals though.