# Players with 400 or more goals in all club competitions (European clubs)

Tags: football, trivia, records

Who are the players that has more than 400 goals in all club competitions, combined for all the teams that they have played. Excluding friendly matches and counting only domestic cups, the domestic top-flight league and official international club games.

Related questions:

- [Players with 300 or more goals for a single team in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/players-with-300-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-top-flight-domestic-league)
- [Players with 400 or more goals for a single team in all competitions (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13145/players-with-300-or-more-goals-for-a-single-team-in-all-competitions-european-c)
- [Players with 300 or more goals in top flight domestic league (European clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/players-with-300-or-more-goals-in-top-flight-domestic-league-european-clubs)

Comment: According to [this list](http://web.archive.org/web/20071007185653/http://goalscorers.narod.ru/Most_successful.htm), this could be Bican, Puskás, Schlosser, Zsengellér, McGrory and Müller.

Comment: Here is one link: https://www.facebook.com/culedefcbarcelona/photos/a.168067396684947.1073741828.168046966686990/595735423918140/?type=3&theater

Comment: Maybe you should clarify a bit what exactly is meant by *all club competitions*. For example, would you count [Lionel Messi's goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi#Career_statistics) for Barcelona B and Barcelona C in lower-level competitions. I guess it would be reasonable to restrict domestic competitions to domestic cups and *top-flight* leagues. (I do not know how likely it is, but it is not unthinkable that some player in some very low competition scored 400 goals.)

Comment: There is also a Wikipedia article [List of men's footballers with 500 or more goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_men%27s_footballers_with_500_or_more_goals). (However, it counts both goals scored for the national team and goals scored in club competitions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting a probably incomplete list as a CW answer. (So that other users can improve it.)

Where the statistics on various sites are different, the numbers given here follow Wikipedia.

| # | Player | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Josef "Pepi" Bican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Bican) | more than 770<sup>JB</sup> |
| 2 | **[Cristiano Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo)** | 701<sup>CR</sup> |
| 3 | **[Lionel Messi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi#Career_statistics)** | 700<sup>LM</sup> |
| 4 | [Ferenc Puskás](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s#Career_statistics) | 606 |
| 5 | [Ference Deák](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_De%C3%A1k_(footballer)) | 576 |
| 6 | [Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller#Career_statistics) | 563<sup>GM</sup> |
| 7 | [Ernst Wilimowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Wilimowski) | 554<sup>EW</sup> |
| 8 | [Jimmy McGrory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_McGrory#Career_statistics) | 538 |
| 9 | **[Robert Lewandowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lewandowski#Career_statistics)** | 513<sup>RL</sup> |
| 10 | [Imre Schlosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imre_Schlosser) | 476<sup>IS</sup> |
| 11 | [Eusébio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eus%C3%A9bio#Career_statistics) | 473<sup>EUS</sup> |
| 12 | **[Zlatan Ibrahimović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlatan_Ibrahimovi%C4%87#Career_statistics)** | 457<sup>ZI</sup> |
| 13 | **[Luis Suárez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Su%C3%A1rez#Career_statistics)** | 440<sup>LS</sup> |
| 14 | **[Karim Benzema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karim_Benzema#Career_statistics)** | 407<sup>KB</sup> |

<sup>JB</sup> More than 805 goals [according to RSSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/players/prolific.html) in all competitive matches. This probably includes 34 international goals.
<sup>GM</sup> He scored 655 goals according to Wikipedia, but this includes 92 goals in Bezirksliga Schwaben and Regionalliga Süd.
<sup>LM</sup> As of 26 Feb 2023. Goals scored for Barcelona B and Barcelona C in lower level competitions are not counted here.
<sup>CR</sup> As of 6 Nov 2022.
<sup>IS</sup> According to Wikipedia, he scored 417 goals in club appearances and 59 international goals.
<sup>EW</sup> He scored 554 goals in official matches [according to RSSSF](http://www.rsssf.com/players/prolific.html).
<sup>EUS</sup>Only goals for Benfica - the rest of his career he played outside of Europe.
<sup>ZI</sup>As of 22 May 2022. 53 goals scored for LA Galaxy are not counted here.
<sup>LS</sup>As of 22 May 2022. 12 goals for Nacional de Montevideo are not counted here.
<sup>RL</sup>As of 26 February 2023. 41 goals for Lech Poznań, 103 goals for Borussia Dortmund and 344 goals for Bayern Munich, 25 goals for Barcelona.
<sup>KB</sup>As of 25 February 2023. 66 goals for Lyon, 341 goals for Real Madrid.